# viewWillAppear not firing for UIViewController that belongs to UITabBarController until I switch tabs

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my iOS app, I have a `UITabBarController`, and its `viewControllers` list looks like `[vc1, vc2]`, which are of class `MyVC1` and `MyVC2` respectively, both of which subclass `UIViewController`. `MyVC1` overrides `viewWillAppear`, and the overwritten version prints something so I know when it is called. (This is to isolate a larger problem I had, which was a view not appearing.)

My issue is that when the app first starts up and `vc1` is the selected tab, nothing is printed, meaning its `viewWillAppear` is not being called. If I switch tabs and then go back to `vc1`, something does get printed, so `vc1`'s `viewWillAppear` is not being called until I switch back to it from another tab.

Is there any way to have `vc1` call `viewWillAppear` as soon as the app starts up, without needing to switch tabs? Honestly, I'm surprised this wasn't the default behavior already.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just made a new test app in Xcode with nothing but a UITabViewController (and its two child view controllers) in Main.storyboard, and when I override viewWillAppear for the first child, my "view will appear" log prints every time (including on app launch).

Here are a couple things that could cause viewWillAppear to not be called:

1. Not calling super somewhere you've overridden viewWillAppear
2. Adding a view controller's view somewhere as a subview without adding the view controller as a child view controller

You also might try seeing if viewWillAppear is getting called for your UITabBarController, and if not, is it being called for its parent or presenting view controller? And so on until you find where the holdup is.

Comment: Thanks, I overrode the `viewWillAppear` of `UITabBarController` without calling `super.viewWillAppear` inside. Stupid mistake...

Comment: I Appreciate this answer. It's a very small thing and normally we miss it. It saved a lot of time. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

if you have Custom UITabBarController, check override func viewWillAppear is call super

in Custom UITabBarController

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated) // this line need
    }
```

Comment: oh,... i see comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following line in viewWillAppear method of your vc1:

```
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

Next, the UITabBarController must be your initial controller.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help. It's still not getting called until I switch to `vc1` from another tab.

Comment: Can u post a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The missing call to super was in my `UITabBarController`.

Comment: What do I do if UITabBarController isn't my initial controller?

Answer (score 0):

make shure in the UITabBarController in the viewwillapear have the super.viewWillAppear(animated) like the following code

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    }
```